# Time complexity of simple python codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, time-complexity

I am trying to compare time complexities of two simple python codes.

```
#1st solution
m = num
cnt = 0
while m > 0:
    if m % 10 == 0:
        cnt = cnt + 1
    m = m // 10

#2nd solution
cnt = 0
snum = str(num)
for digit in snum:
    if digit == "0":
        cnt = cnt + 1
```

I think that the first solution is O(n^2) and the second is O(n).
Am I correct?

Comment: How did you arrive at O(n^2)?

Comment: Have you considered testing these with various _n_ and timing the results?

Answer (score 0):

1st solution is O(log n). It cuts an order of magnitude per iteration. So does the 2nd solution, so it's the same. Maybe a bit clearer if the output from the code is also included, with e.g. n=123456789 (num = 10-digit, log(n)~=10)

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    num = 123456789
    m = num
    cnt = 0
    while m > 0:
        if m % 10 == 0:
            cnt = cnt + 1
        m = m // 10
        print(str(m))        
    print("------------")

    cnt = 0
    snum = str(num)
    for digit in snum:
        if digit == "0":
            cnt = cnt + 1
        print(str(snum))
```

Outputs:

```
    12345678
    1234567
    123456
    12345
    1234
    123
    12
    1
    0
    ------------
    123456789
    123456789
    123456789
    123456789
    123456789
    123456789
    123456789
    123456789
    123456789
```

Comment: ignore print statement it's just for testing

Answer (score 0):

**O(log10base(m))** if we consider m as a number, and **O( len(m) )** if we consider it as a string. both are the same.